Whatever good I do, the same amount of reward is given to my parents automatically because they raised me , fed me and taught me all right and wrong
Please refer me an authentic hadith , where it proves that whatever little to more good deed I do my parents are rewarded and the same amount of good deed is written in their account because they raised me to be this capable
Is this true ?
